# Index on a column updated very frequently

Tags: sql, oracle, indexing

I need to create an index on a column for better performance. the column is of type timestamp and would be a function-based index.
The issue is : this column is updated very frequently.

The Oracle documentation said to do not index columns that are modified frequently.

So is there a better way to query this column ?

**Edit**:

In the following query, the column is VALIDATIONTIME:

```
select * 
from orders 
where VALIDATIONTIME between
  TO_TIMESTAMP('2016/03/06 10:45:18', 'YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS')
and
  TO_TIMESTAMP('2016/03/15 19:50:18', 'YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS');
```

Comment: The index should be built only if it can help with performance issues. The trick is to locate the bottleneck in your processes. If your updates are taking too long - don't create an index, if your selects are your problem - do create one. There is no single rule to follow, and Oracle's documentation only recommends what is the best-practice in these cases.

Comment: As the person above mentioned, its just a trade off. Test it for your application, and weigh up the results against what the end goal is.

Answer (score 0):

A timestamp can help ensure high cardinality so it may very well be a good choice but it really depends on the predicate you use to access the data.
The timestamp column will only have good cardinality if rows are inserted singly in different units of work! 
Now I know nothing about this table or its usage patterns, but it really depends on the predicate you use to access the data.

We rarely ask questions about what happened at a precise microsecond. So it's very rare to see a predicate of the form `where timestamp_column = some precise value`. You're far more likely to see a range expression such as `where timestamp_column between :ts1 and :ts2`, and more often than not that predicate will have a companion.

So as a gross generalisation, you could consider:

- placing the timestamp column as a second or subsequent column of a composite index
- defining the table as range partitioned bounded on a day's, week's or month's start and end timestamps, if the cardinality and distribution justify it; or
- even removing the timestamp from the index keys altogether and storing it with the unique index.

All depending on the query characteristics.